# change hokuyo orientation in urdf

Tags: gazebo, urdf, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a urdf file with the Hokuyo facing downwards.  I would like to change the orientation make the Hokuyo point upwards. What would be the best way to do it?

```
<xacro:macro name="hokuyo_mount_inverted" params="name parent *origin length ros_topic update_rate min_angle max_angle">
 <xacro:beam_8020 name="${name}_sensor_beam" parent="${parent}" length="${length}">
   <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
 </xacro:beam_8020>
 <!--<xacro:aluminium_sheet name="${name}_plate" parent="${name}_sensor_beam" 
                       thickness="${0.125*INCH_TO_M}" length="0.06" width="0.12">
                        <origin xyz="${0.5*INCH_TO_M} 0 ${length/2}" rpy="${M_PI/2} 0 ${M_PI/2}" />-->
 <xacro:aluminium_sheet name="${name}_plate" parent="${name}_sensor_beam" 
                       thickness="${0.125*INCH_TO_M}" length="0.06" width="0.12">
      <origin xyz="-${0.5*INCH_TO_M} 0 ${length/2}" rpy="${M_PI/2} 0 ${M_PI/2}" />
 </xacro:aluminium_sheet>
 <xacro:hokuyo_04lx_laser name="${name}" parent="${name}_plate" ros_topic="${ros_topic}" update_rate="${update_rate}" min_angle="${min_angle}" max_angle="${max_angle}">
   <origin xyz="0 0 ${0.125*INCH_TO_M}" rpy="0 0 0" />
 </xacro:hokuyo_04lx_laser>
</xacro:macro>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186790/change-hokuyo-orientation-in-urdf/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change the hokuyo_041x_laser's origin element to have non-zero values in the RPY attribute.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on 2014-08-07**:
I tried. But it gave me an error